# Array list get sum of the alternate result

Tags: javascript

Is there a function how can I easily get the sum of alternating result:

Here is my simple raw list:

```
let x = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ,7];

expected result:
sum by first: 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16
sum by second: 2 + 4 + 6 = 12
sum by third: 3 + 6 = 9
```

just want to get the sum by alternating index, any suggetsions/comments TIA

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
let x = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ,7];

function sumBy(firstelem){
  var i = firstelem -1,
  sum =0;
  for(let k=i; k<x.length; k=k+2){
    sum = sum + x[k];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumBy(1));
console.log(sumBy(2));
console.log(sumBy(3));
```

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think OP's expectation is  matching for 3 and '1 and 2'. if you see for 1 and 2 there's a gap of one element. I believe the gap should be one for '3' as well, for consistency. Isn't it?

Comment: What's the common pattern in `sum by first` and `sum by third`?

Comment: That one seems to be working because for each `take`, different result is returned. So it's certainly not scalable. for  `skipTake(5, myList)`  another `else if` in `filtered`  might have to be inserted.

Comment: @mplungjan not sure if that's sarcasm :p but OP says in the question, `just want to get the sum by alternating index,`. So guess it's valid to assume, the indices should alternate in all cases. They wouldn't increase by 2 or 3 at some or the other times. But I guess we can only debate, only they will be able to clarify the expectations.

Comment: Seems you will have that discussion with Steve ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom function for these as follows:

```js
const myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let skipTake = (take, list) => {
  let filtered = list.filter((a, i) => {
    if (take == 1) {
      return i % 2 == 0;
    } else if (take == 2) {
      return i != 0 && i % take == 1;
    } else {
      return i != 0 && (i + 1) % take == 0;
    }
  });
  return filtered.reduce((agg, cur) => agg += cur);
}

console.log("first", skipTake(1, myList))
console.log("second", skipTake(2, myList))
console.log("third", skipTake(3, myList))
console.log("fourth", skipTake(4, myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do the trick

The index inside the loop starts from 1 and goes till length-1 because of your specific requirements.

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const index = 3; //for example
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < x.length + 1; i++)
  sum += (i % index == 0) ? x[i - 1] : 0;

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: A reduce would be more elegant

Answer (score -1):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Change the if statement to change which indexes are selected. This one will select all even numbered indexes.

```
let x = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ,7];

let y = x.filter((element, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
    return element;
  }
}).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: That is only doing the "2"

Comment: Mmm, functional… can also easily be turned into a function where the modulus value is a variable…

Comment: How would you add `2 + 4 + 6 = 12` with this approach?

Comment: Learn about modulo: x % 2 === 0 will give even, x % 2 === 0 will give odd numbers, x % 3 === 0 will give every 3 numbers etc.

Comment: @SteveBunting `0%2 === 0`/ `0%3 === 0``/0%4 === 0` so every time the first element will be considered.